# Move semantics, or rather compiler does not recognize rvalue when constructed?

Tags: c++, move

I tried to do implement hashmap and add move semantics to it.. but for some reason at a certain case rvalue is not recognized, can anyone detect why? and explain?
This is the Insertion declerations:

```
inline bool Insert      (Key_t const&   key,
                         Value_t const& val,
                         iterator*      itr = nullptr)      {
    return Insert(value_type(key, val), itr);
}

/** see comments above */
inline bool Insert      (Key_t&&        key,
                         Value_t const& val,
                         iterator*      itr = nullptr)      {
    return Insert(value_type(std::forward<Key_t>(key), val), itr);
}

/** see comments above */
inline bool Insert      (Key_t const&   key,
                         Value_t&&      val,
                         iterator*      itr = nullptr)      {
    return Insert(value_type(key, std::forward<Value_t>(val)), itr);
}

/** see comments above */
inline bool Insert      (Key_t&&        key,
                         Value_t&&      val,
                         iterator*      itr = nullptr)      {
    return Insert(value_type(std::forward<Key_t>(key), std::forward<Value_t>(val)), itr);
}
```

and this is my tester:

```
typedef HashMap_T<std::string, int> D;
D d;
d.Insert("Alon", 1);
```

Now I expected it to go to Key_t&& and Value_t&&, but for some reason it goes to Key_t const& and Value_t&&...

but the std::string that has been constructed in the insertion would be deleted right after, why is it not recognized as rvalue??

***EDIT***
of course string literals are lvalue, but I am inserting to string.. just so you understand, this does go to the Key_t&& and Value_t&&:

```
typedef HashMap_T<std::string, int> D;
D d;
d.Insert(std::string("Alon"), 1);
```

Thanks,
Alon

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/TRAZUV) if I write a complete test case around your code snippets. Perhaps you could post your test case, so we can reproduce exactly what you're doing?

Comment: Thanks buddy, I tested it on VS 2010 - does not work, on 2012 - works !!